# google analytics custom tag tracking

Tags: tags, google-analytics, tagging

we have pages that has tags. we want a report based on these tags. Those tags are around 0~20 for one page.
 how can we implement in analytics.

```
view page: tags
```

15   Page1 : apple, pine, five

3    Page2 : tree, pine, sea, shore

9    Page3 : pine, sea, five, bike

```
we want to see how many tags seen  like :
```

tag view

apple 15

pine 15+3+9=27

five  15+9=24

tree 9

sea 3+9=12

I think I can arrange shows but I cant define more than five custom variable.

Comment: I assume you are talking about a tag cloud and want to know which tags are being shown in a tag cloud?  How actionable do you really think knowing that is? What do you expect to be able to do with that knowledge? You should be tracking stuff users do on your site, not what your own site spits out.

Comment: Yes when you put your tags in a box in your site it is called tag cloud. In our system tags are important and I'm asked to set up a tracking mech. based on them.

Comment: I highly suggest you push back on this. I've had many clients ask for tracking on tag clouds and result is always the same.  No easy way to fully track tag clouds, and regardless of how it has been implemented, results have always been the same: no actions have come from it.  It's just not actionable.  It is useful to know which tags the user clicks on.  It is not useful to know which links were displayed unless there is some kind of marketing effort specifically tied to each link being shown.  I mean think about it - are you tracking all your other links that are *displayed* on the page?

Comment: I also want to say that for the people I actually have implemented tracking for tag clouds for (tracking every tag shown), it was with yahoo web analytics or omniture site catalyst. I seriously do not recommend doing this with GA. GA imposes a limit of 500 requests per visit to be sent to their server - that is for ALL requests, including page views. You will burn through that limit super quick trying to implement this and will stand to lose tracking on other events and page views.

Comment: I thought about that :) But never thought about saturation. Thanks for suggestion. I heard yahoo is hard to be accepted. They refuse.

Comment: Just to chime in, @Crayon Violent is 1000% right about this.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use a single custom variable slot… lets use #5 for this example:

It’s worth keeping in mind this important point:
“The total combined length of any custom variable name and value may not exceed 64 bytes.”
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html#usage

So that means that we need to keep the amount of data you send to Google as small as possible if it’s all going to fit in a single custom variable.  Because a single tag name can contain quite a few characters I’d recommend using the tag’s ID number instead.  Most likely your database is storing all your tags and each tag does have a primary ID that corresponds to it.  Example:

1 = apple
2 = pine
3 = five
4 = tree
5 = sea
6 = shore
7 = bike

If you pass only the ID over to Google Analytics then you’re going to save a lot of space and give you more room to fit all the possible tags that a single page might have been tagged with.

Now lets look at some code…

```
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
          5,             // This custom var is set to slot #5.
          'tags',   // The name of the custom variable.
          '1-2-3-,',      // Sets the value(s).  Here is where we pass the tag IDs.  In this case we know these equal apple, pine, five
           3             // Sets the scope to page-level.
       ]);
```

And as another example..

```
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
          5,             // This custom var is set to slot #5.
          'pageTags',   // The name of the custom variable.
          '4-2-5-6-',      // Sets the value(s).  Here is where we pass the tag IDs.  In this case we know these equal tree, pine, sea, shore
           3             // Sets the scope to page-level.
       ]);
```

You can then filter in Google Analtyics to find page views that have specific tags.  Example:  If you only want to find page views tagged with “pine” then do a search for “-2-”.  Note that I’m using a hyphen after every number.  This helps us separate the numbers.  If you want to run more complex filters in google analytics you can get more complex using regex as your filter criteria.

This should work, just keep in mind that the values + the name of your custom variable can not be longer then 64 bytes.   So you need to keep your tag ID numbers as tiny as possible (2 digits max probably) and try not to go over 6 tags per page.

Example:
Custom Variable Name: Tags
Values:  1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-22

Your custom variable name above takes up 4 bytes and your values take up another 57 so your total bytes used is just under the maximum 64 bytes.  If you start getting into three digit tag IDs then you're going to quickly shrink your options on how many tags you can pass.

Hope this helps!